# Autologin in cross site domain

Tags: javascript, authentication, authorization, cross-domain

I have more than 140 id and password of different web site. I want to open each web site dynamically set set id password and login.

I had try lots of thing ex. iframe, frameset, parent window access, url scripts passed.
but its not working for security. Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: If you can get your hands on a browser from the 90's I'm sure it wont have the same pesky security that protects you from malicious websites, such as the one you want to write

Comment: @JaromandaX i am using chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Selenium IDE plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/) (Firefox only) from [Selenium project](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Selenium IDE plugin lets you record your actions on any page and it will generate a script, something like (pseudocode):

```
openPage('http://google.com');
click("#signinElement");
click("#usernameInputElement")
enter("username");
click("#passwordInputElement")
enter("password");
click("#submitButton")
// ...
openPage('http://amazon.com');
// ...
```

Then you can edit it, add a loop around the whole script and iterate over your list of credentials.

*assuming you want to do it locally and not to create a website*

Answer (score 0):

Cross origin issues will indeed occur if you try to change input values on a login provider's web page. **To get closer to automation**, I suggest opening the browser console after the login page has loaded.
Console, as you probably know, is not just for log, it allows you to write Javascript commands to the page.
If you prepare the following code in advance, all is left to do is just to **copy and paste in the console**, to control the page elements.

1. Collect the names of the input and submit elements of each of your account providers.
   Something like the following:

   `var logins = {
     yahoo: { 
       url:'https://login.yahoo.com', 
       usernameInputName: 'username', 
       usernameInputValue: 'YOUR_USER_ID_HERE',
       usernameStep: true, 
       usernameStepSubmit: 'signin',
       passwordInputName: 'passwd',
       passwordInputValue: 'YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE',
       submit: 'signin'
     },
     //google: {...
   };`
2. Open your account login page, in this example - https://login.yahoo.com.
   Yahoo has two steps of signing in, first - you put your username, submit, then put your password and then submit again. In such case, `logins["yahoo"].usernameStep` is set to `true`
3. If `usernameStep` is `false` you submit only once by "clicking" dynamically on `logins[LOGIN_NAME].submit`:

`{`

`document.getElementsByName(login.usernameInputName)[0].value = login.usernameInputValue;`
`document.getElementsByName(login.passwordInputName)[0].value = login.passwordInputValue;`
`document.getElementsByName(login.submit)[0].click();`

`}`

4. If `usernameStep` is `true` you use  `document.getElementsByName(login.usernameStepSubmit)[0].click();` after putting the username, and then proceed to password and submit.

Hope this helps.